# layering divs and css

Tags: html, css

I am still learning how css and divs work together, and would like the blur effect to happen only on the background of each rollover, and not on the red image overlaying it. I don't know what the best way to approach this would be.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottschaffer/nz3nL9bu/1/)

CSS:

```
.bg {
    width:100%;
    padding:70px 0px 70px 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    width:94%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.itemLeft {
    width:48%;
    background-color:#777;
    float:left;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
.item {
    width:100%;
    background-position:center center;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.item img {
    text-align:center;
}
.item:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    background-position:center center;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="itemLeft">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x150/a00000" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemLeft">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/128x150/f00000" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blur filter is applied to the `.item` element *and* its children, therefore the `img` element is always going to be blurred if it is a child.

One option would be to make `.item` and `img` sibling elements instead:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqcj09zc/)

```
<div class="itemLeft">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/128x150/a00000" />
</div>
```

In doing so, you could absolutely position the `.item` element *relative* to the parent element, `.itemLeft`, so that it fills the entire element using `top: 0`/`left: 0`/`bottom: 0`/`right: 0`.

```
.itemLeft {
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/") center center / auto auto no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Then position the `img` element to [establish a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) so that it appears *above* the sibling.

```
.wrapper img {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Finally, use the selector `.itemLeft:hover .item` to apply the blur filter to the `.item` element. In doing so, it will now occur when hovering over the parent element rather than the `.item` element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqcj09zc/)

```css
.bg {
    padding: 70px 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 94%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.itemLeft {
    width:48%;
    background-color:#777;
    float:left;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/") center center / auto auto no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.wrapper img {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.itemLeft:hover .item {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    background-position:center center;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="itemLeft">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/128x150/a00000" />
        </div>
        <div class="itemLeft">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/128x150/f00000" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation! obviously, from the items you removed from my code, I am still learning what attributes i need and what i don't to make it react the way i want.